# Show that AX is the median of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle. Choose $P\in BC$ such that $BC = 3 \cdot P C$ and let $X$ be the intersection point of the lines $AP$ and $CM_c$. Prove that the line $AX$ is the median of $\Delta AM_cC$. Here $M_c$ denotes the base point of the median starting from C. Picture:

[image: triangle]

Can someone tell me what connections or theorems I am supposed to use to prove this? I can't see any similar triangles and I tried to just make some equations from the given condition $BC=3PC$ but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to cover this and tons of similar problems is to take a look at the theorems of Ceva and Menelaus:

- [Ceva's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem)
- [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem)

Note that in most sources, proportions of segments built on the same line are considered to be signed.

Here is an application of Menelaus' Theorem for the case of $\Delta CBM_c$ with respect to the "secant line" AXP. We have the relation:
$$
1 
=
\underbrace{\frac{PC}{PB}}_{=-1/2} \cdot
\underbrace{\frac{AB}{AM_c}}_{=2} \cdot
\frac{XM_c}{XC} \ .
$$
This gives the signed value $-1$ for the third proportion. This means $X$ is the mid point of $CM_c$.